# How to handle onSwipe event in a ListActivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, swipe, android-listfragment, swipe-gesture

I Need to add **LeftSwipe event  to a List Activity**.The left Swipe will act as back button event `(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)`. i.e The Left Swipe Will Navigate me to the previous Activity.

Any Possible Ways other Than `Fragments or ListFragments` as i use `CustomArrayAdapter` to set view for my List .

> Note : Using AsyncTask to make a Service call to get Values for my List

Thanks in Advance ..!!